# Remove everything else from the String using regular expression

Tags: regex, groovy

I have this regular expression which is what is allowed in the String.

```
    ^\pL*['#-]?\pL*\$
```

The requirements have changed and now I need to drop everything else from the String. For example only one of these special characters ', #, and - is allowed.

How can I change this regex to drop everything else that does not fit this ?

Here is the list of expected values:

```
JohnO'Connell  -> allowed. should be as is.
JohnDias       -> allowed. should be as is.
JohnOConnell'  -> allowed. should be as is.
JohnOConnell#  -> allowed. should be as is.
JohnOConnell-  -> allowed. should be as is.
JohnOConnell-# -> should return JohnOConnell-
JohnOConn34ell -> should return JohnOConnell
*JohnOConnell  -> should return JohnOConnell
JohnOConnell*  -> should return JohnOConnell
JohnOConn$%ell -> should return JohnOConnell
```

Thanks

Comment: Your regex seems not correct. Shouldn't `\pL` be `\p{L}`? Also you are escaping `$` which doesn't seem right. For now your question is unclear (at least for me). Maybe beside posting regex give us examples of input, expected output, and explanation why this output is expected.

Comment: I it is hard to understand, what you want to match. Can you give some examples?

Comment: I have additional information to the question. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: This question has provided additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you could do it this way:

```
// Test data
def tests = [ [ input:"JohnO'Connell",   output:"JohnO'Connell" ],
              [ input:"JohnDias",        output:"JohnDias" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConnell'",   output:"JohnOConnell'" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConnell#",   output:"JohnOConnell#" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConnell-",   output:"JohnOConnell-" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConnell-#",  output:"JohnOConnell-" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConn34ell",  output:"JohnOConnell" ],
              [ input:"*JohnOConnell",   output:"JohnOConnell" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConnell*",   output:"JohnOConnell" ],
              [ input:"JohnOConn\$%ell", output:"JohnOConnell" ] ]

String normalize( String input ) {
    int idx = 0
    input.replaceAll( /[^A-Za-z'#\-]/, '' )  // remove all disallowed chars
         .replaceAll( /['#\-]/ ) { match ->  // replace 2nd+ instance of special chars
             idx++ == 0 ? match : ''
         }
}

tests.each {
    assert normalize( it.input ) == it.output
}
```